# How to add all object to list in Python without using empty list before for loop?

Tags: list, python-2.7, append

I'd like to use append or extend objects to list without using the empty list before for loop.

I wonder if any function or method implementing it so that it can append them to the list then moves the next line in the code.

My issue when I use an empty list is that I need to move the rest of the lines of the code in order to use a new list.

This is outputs:

```
[u'person_0']
[u'person_0', u'chair_0']
[u'person_0', u'chair_0', u'chair_1']
[u'person_0', u'chair_0', u'chair_1', u'book_0']
[u'person_0', u'chair_0', u'chair_1', u'book_0', u'bottle_0']
```

I only need the last output:

```
[u'person_0', u'chair_0', u'chair_1', u'book_0', u'bottle_0']
```

This is part of my code:

```
                    my_tf_id = []
                    my_dis =[]
                    for obj_class in objects:

                        rospy.logdebug('Found ' + str(len(objects[obj_class])) + ' object(s) of type ' + obj_class)

                        for obj_type_index, coordinates in enumerate(objects[obj_class]):
#                     
                            rospy.logdebug('...' + obj_class + ' ' + str(obj_type_index) + ' at ' + str(coordinates))

                            ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = coordinates
                            y_center = ymax - ((ymax - ymin) / 2)
                            x_center = xmax - ((xmax - xmin) / 2)

                            detected_object = DetectedObject()
                            detected_object.type.data = obj_class
                            detected_object.image_x.data = xmin
                            detected_object.image_y.data = ymin
                            detected_object.image_width.data = xmax - xmin
                            detected_object.image_height.data = ymax - ymin


                            publish_tf = False
                            if self._current_pc is None:
                                rospy.loginfo('No point cloud information available to track current object in scene')


                            else:

                                pc_list = list(pc2.read_points(self._current_pc, skip_nans=True, field_names=('x', 'y', 'z'), uvs=[(x_center, y_center)]))

                                if len(pc_list) > 0:

                                    publish_tf = True

                                    tf_id = obj_class + '_' + str(obj_type_index)        #object_number

                                    my_tf_id.append(tf_id)
                                    print my_tf_id
```

**Update:**

I used this example to make it easy.

I don't need to shift the rest of the code's lines for some reason.

```
x = []
L = [2.0, 3, 5, 7, 11 , 9 , 10]
for i, j in enumerate(L) :
    x.append(j)
    print x
```

the output, it is normal:

```
[2.0]
[2.0, 3]
[2.0, 3, 5]
[2.0, 3, 5, 7]
[2.0, 3, 5, 7, 11]
[2.0, 3, 5, 7, 11, 9]
[2.0, 3, 5, 7, 11, 9, 10]
```

when shifting this line `print x` toward the left, the output was as below, it is also normal:

```
[2.0, 3, 5, 7, 11, 9, 10]
```

I'd like to change structure previous example to this example:

```
L = [2.0, 3, 5, 7, 11 , 9 , 10]

    for i, j in enumerate(L) :
        x = []
        x.append(j) #if any function or method gather them in this line, and moves to the next lines.
        print x
```

**NOTE:**
I don't want to modify this line:`for i, j in enumerate(L) :`

Please help me or make any suggestion.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you want to avoid creating the empty list before the loop? Even if you avoid the empty list you need some equivalent data structure to accumulate the values.

Comment: Every object has many values (15 values) and I am training it online using many features in order to identify a certain person as a target to the robot. I need the list for comparing among them using such as min, max,....etc. when I use an empty list, I need to add all values. BUT without an empty list, it will need a person's index. I think that, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, it sounds like what you are looking for is a generator.

So instead of:

```
x = []
L = [2.0, 3, 5, 7, 11 , 9 , 10]
for i, j in enumerate(L) :
    x.append(j)

y = x[3]
```

You would instead use:

```
L = [2.0, 3, 5, 7, 11 , 9 , 10]

def results(index):
    for i, j in enumerate(L) :
        if i == index:
            yield j

y = results(3)
```

Here `y` is a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). You can retrieve the value with either:

```
print(*y)
```

Or

```
print(next(y))
```